# Using 20 A with a slip ring, is it better to go for more channels for redundancy, higher amps to stop maximum load, or both?

Tags: current, connector, slip-ring

I'm planning on designing a power strip with the use of a slip ring.
The maximum ampre I would be output is 20A to a minimum of 2.5A.

I've found some slip rings on Aliexpress that are 20A across 3 channels for roughly £15.
But there is also options to purchase 30A across 3 channels at £16 or 6 channels for both 20A & 30A at over double the price of the 3 channels.

All these options has me curious as to what might be the best option for my project.
So I would someone to advise on which of the options would be the best for me to use?

- 3 channel with 20A - Nothing changes
- 3 channel with 30A - Have 10 Amperes of over sight that the slip ring will not be at maximum load at any time
- 6 channel with 20A - 6 channels provides an extra channel of redundancy so should 1 of the brushes fail, I can still safely transmit 20A to the socket.
- 6 channel with 30A - Best of both worlds, have the redundancy of extra brushes but also extra 10 amperes of oversight.

From a EE point of view (as I'm not an EE) what would be the best and safest option for me to use?

Edit:
The plan is to build an modular power strip, that can be used anywhere in the world, this would be directly plugged into a mains wall socket the maximum being 20 amps in the odd occasion but more than likely it will be 16 amps.. the 360 degrees part is I want to be able to rotate the outlet for the purposes of cable management but also if the user has space constraints for a particular plug for example those smart sockets you can get. Starting out I would buying the product on small quantities from AliExpress for prototyping after which I would get in contact with a wholesaler.

Comment: This is a judgement call that depends on how critical your application is and how much the slip rings are going to wear again dependent on your application. You have not detailed this. The only thing I can say is that if you using Ali Express building in some headroom in the current is a good idea.

Comment: First: is this a power strip for mains voltage?  Do you require continuous rotation or just the ability to rotate through 360 degrees?  If continuous rotation, what is the speed?  I would not trust a £15 part from Aliexpress to transmit almost 5kW.

Comment: Aliexpress is a retail channel and the seller may or may not be offering a product which meets the specifications they claim. For example, they may have already taken into account that you will derate the item by inflating the capability. Best to find the real manufacturer and evaluate their data.

Comment: The plan is to build an modular power strip, that can be used anywhere in the world, this would be directly plugged into a mains wall socket the maximum being 20 amps in the odd occasion but more than likely it will be 16 amps.. the 360 degrees part is I want to be able to rotate the outlet for the purposes of cable management but also if the user has space constraints for a particular plug for example those smart sockets you can get. Starting out I would buying the product on small quantities from AliExpress for prototyping after which I would get in contact with a wholesaler.

Comment: You should edit this information into your question.

Comment: you can buy off the shelf what you are trying to build

Answer (score 1):

Slip rings are not necessary here; they're big, they're a pain to terminate, the contacts need to have the corrosion wiped off them if they're stationary for any length of time, which yours will be. Quality slip rings are expensive. Quality slip rings that can handle kW of power are very expensive.

It sounds like you don't need a slip ring, just a flexible mechanical coupling that can rotate through 360 degrees, not continuously. A suitably-managed length of wire that can twist with the coupling will work just as well if not better than a slip ring and will save you the headache of having to deal with a perfectly unnecessary fire hazard.

Comment: So basically create a section in the plastic socket that allows it to rotate up to 360 in either direction but there be a small blockade to stop to rotating any further?

Comment: Yes and just let the wire flex inside the center space. There are specific ways you can arrange the wire to minimize strain but I forget what the technical term is. Stranded wire, of course.